# Fetch response body using ContainerResponseFilter

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to catch the response entity stream using `getEntityStream()` of `ContainerResponseContext`. Below is the code:

```java
public String getResponseEntityStream(ContainerResponseContext context) throws IOException {

    OutputStream originalStream = context.getEntityStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    context.setEntityStream(baos);

    String body = baos.toString();
    baos.writeTo(originalStream);
    baos.close();
    context.setEntityStream(originalStream);
    return body;
}
```

I call the above method in below code to fetch the entire response stream:

```java
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {

    StringBuilder sbResponse = new StringBuilder();
    
    sbResponse.append(" - Response Entity Class: ").append(responseContext.getEntityClass())
        .append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    sbResponse.append(" - Response Entity Stream: ").append(getResponseEntityStream(responseContext))
        .append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    System.out.println("HTTP RESPONSE : " + "\n" + sbResponse.toString());
}
```

**My question:**

In the above code, `Response Entity Stream` is always blank. I am just trying to read the entire response entity stream and print it to show how the original stream looks like, before I do some processing on the stream. Where am I making the mistake? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I am able to fetch the response body using `WriterInterceptor`. However the `WriterInterceptor` is invoked only when there is a response payload. I am using `ContainerResponseFilter` as I want to read response details even when there is no payload. Also, Writer Interceptor does not help `getStatus()` and `getStatusInfo()` like the `ContainerResponseFilter`. Is there a way that I can combine the data of both `ContainerResponseFilter` and `WriterInterceptor` in a string and print the entire response in logs. may be by using Thread Local?

Answer (score 2):

`ContainerResponseContext` has two methods being confused here:

- [getEntity()](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/ws/rs/container/containerresponsecontext#getEntity()) - returns the actual Java entity object before it has been written
- [getOutputStream()](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/ws/rs/container/containerresponsecontext#getEntityStream()) - returns the `OutputStream` used for writing the entity. The entity is written during the writer interceptor phase.

The `OutputStream` can be decorated by a user-provided `OutputStream` which does what is required, for instance, it logs the information and writes the data to the original stream. This new decorator `OutputStream` can be registered by [ContainerResponseContext#setEntityStream()](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/ws/rs/container/containerresponsecontext#setEntityStream(java.io.OutputStream)).

Jersey comes with [LoggingFeature](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest31x/logging_chapter.html#logging) / [ServerLoggingFilter](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/3.1/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/ServerLoggingFilter.java) / [LoggingInterceptor](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/3.1/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/logging/LoggingInterceptor.java). Together, they do exactly this logging, the filter decorates the original `OutputStream` and they log the entity, headers, and other response-related information.

In those Jersey classes, you can see how [ContainerRequestContext#setProperty()](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/ws/rs/container/containerrequestcontext#setProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)) and [WriterInterceptorContext#getProperty](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/3.0/apidocs/jakarta/ws/rs/ext/interceptorcontext#getProperty(java.lang.String)) are used for passing the information from the `Filter` to the `Interceptor`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a misunderstanding about the usage of the method `ContainerResponseContext#getEntityStream()`. One isn't supposed to read from an `OutputStream`.

As @jan-supol says in his answer, you can decorate the `OutputStream` with a logger, for example.

But, if you still want to log your response the way you're doing, you could retrieve the entity directly.

The code you wrote:

```java
    OutputStream originalStream = context.getEntityStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // it's empty
    context.setEntityStream(baos); // why? you're replacing the original os by this one
    String body = baos.toString(); // empty stream, empty string
    baos.writeTo(originalStream); // you're writing your empty stream to os, which doesn't affect the os
    baos.close();
    context.setEntityStream(originalStream); // assignment rollback?
    return body; // returning an empty string
```

The way I'd do it:

```java
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response) {
        if (response.hasEntity()) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(" - Response Entity Class: ").append(response.getEntityClass())
                    .append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            // in order to work, you should guarantee that entity has reasonable #toString implementation
            Object entity = response.getEntity();
            sb.append(" - Response Entity Stream: ").append(entity.toString())
                    .append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            System.out.println("HTTP RESPONSE : " + "\n" + sb.toString());
        }
    }
```